# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android

i am trying to set up an alarm manager app but whenever i run my app a run-time exception pops up telling me the Toolbar can't be inflated and i can't seem to figure out why.

i commented out the code for the toolbar in the xml and also the mainactivity  in an attempt to debug the app. but the same error appears for the floating action button which i also have in my layout which indicated to me the problem wasn't the Toolbar but something else.

this is the logcat :

```
Process: com.example.alarmmanager, PID: 17402
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alarmmanager/com.example.alarmmanager.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)

     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.alarmmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)

        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.alarmmanager-kj3KUbYybMt0cIjBxRbFUw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
```

MainActivity.java :

```
private FloatingActionButton mAddReminderButton;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    AlarmCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;
    AlarmReminderDbHelper alarmReminderDbHelper = new AlarmReminderDbHelper(this);
    ListView reminderListView;
    ProgressDialog prgDialog;

    public static final int VEHICLE_LOADER = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        //by the way the (MainActivitty.java:34 ) 
        //reference in the logcat is this line        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar (mToolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);


        reminderListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        reminderListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

        mCursorAdapter = new AlarmCursorAdapter(this, null);
        reminderListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

        reminderListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddReminderActivity.class);

                Uri currentVehicleUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(AlarmReminderContract.AlarmReminderEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);

                // Set the URI on the data field of the intent
                intent.setData(currentVehicleUri);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mAddReminderButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        mAddReminderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddReminderActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(VEHICLE_LOADER, null, (android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object>) this);
}
```

the xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="16dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:background="@color/myColor" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_reminder_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/no_card_details"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabSize="normal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Build gradle :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:+'
    implementation 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: please share java code.

Comment: Its working fine in my studio..Please post your java file and xml file completely to resolve the issue

Comment: @Javacoder i have shared the code please have a look at it

Comment: @Pranita i have shared the java code and the xml as-well please have a look at it

Comment: Remove toolbar from xml and run the app

Comment: i already did that as i have mentioned above. but the same error appeared for the floating action button.

Comment: can you share manifest file

Comment: the code shared by you works fine on my machine..which android studio version you are using??

Answer (score 0):

it could be an issue with the support `v7:28.0.0`

please downgrade your library to `27.1.0` and see if the problem persist

For example :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0' // appcompat library
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
```

You need to change the compile version and build tools to 27 too.

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.1.0"
```

after sync , rebuild and clean your project